# How to display the first element in array with for loop

Tags: flutter, for-loop, dart, flutter-web

I am looping through an array i.e 'companies' using the for loop. I want to display the first element in this array using 'for loop' without having to do it this way 'companies[0].name'. Here is what I have done which works but I need to use them for loop.

```
    child: Column(
      children: < Widget > [
        // for (var item in companies)
        companies.length > 0 ?
        Text(
          '${companies[0].name}'.toUpperCase(), // how can i replace this using the for loop
          style: TextStyle(
            color: AppColor.white,
          ),
        ) :
        Text('No Company Assigned '),
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: `companies.length > 0 ? ...companies.map((c) => Text('${c.name}')) : Text('No Company Assigned ')`

Comment: why don't you want to use `companies[0].name` and why do you need to use `for loop`, can you clarify your question?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh because i will still need the for loop later and one because i would like to know if there's a work-around this using the for loop.

Comment: @pskink your suggestion displays all the  elements in the array. How can i modify it to only display the first element?

Comment: Ok you just want to use `for loop` inside  `Column` right?

Comment: wait, if you want first element what do you need a loop for? what do you need a `Column` for if it has just one child? what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh exactly

Comment: You may have your purpose, I'm answering inline function for column.

Comment: @pskink for now I just ned to display the first element to have something I can show my client. But I need to have this for implementation because I will need it later for the actual implementation

Comment: @pskink this works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an inline function to create a loop. Though, I will suggest keep the logic simple here. And most prefer using map in your case as @pskink describe on comment section.

```dart
 Column(
        children: [
          () {
            // do the thing you want and return
            return companies.isEmpty
                ? Text('No Company Assigned ')
                : Text(companies.first.toUpperCase());
          }(),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListBuilder like below example, if its first element return your widget, else return empty container.

```
final List<String> entries = <String>['A', 'B', 'C'];
final List<int> colorCodes = <int>[600, 500, 100];

ListView.builder(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
  itemCount: entries.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return index == 0  ? Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[colorCodes[index]],
      child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${entries[index]}')),
    ): Container();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [mapIndexed](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/mapIndexed.html) or [forEachIndexed](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/forEachIndexed.html) extension methods from the collection package.

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

item.forEachIndexed((index, element) {
  print('index: $index, element: $element');
});
```